# Comparing date stored in date and varchar columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, plsql

I have a simple table, in which I have to store date information both in DATE and VARCHAR2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE date_test(date_in_varchar VARCHAR2(30), date_in_date DATE);

INSERT INTO date_test values ('06/21/2017 01:30:00 AM', to_date('06/21/2017 01:01:03 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'));

INSERT INTO date_test values ('06/22/2017 02:45:00 AM', to_date('06/22/2017 05:06:01 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'));

INSERT INTO date_test values ('06/23/2017 05:51:20 AM', to_date('06/23/2017 12:00:05 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'));
```

As you can see, format of data is '***MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM***'. I have to prepare comparisons between date passed in variable *l_attr_val* format **'MM/DD/YYYY'** and ones stored in the table. Now my question is: What is the best and safest way, to write queries for filters: **equals, like, greater, lower**, to be sure, that I won't face implicit conversion? I assume, that query would be different for values stored as date and for values stored as varchar.

CASE 1: Date is stored in `DATE` column and it has information about `day, month, year, hour, minutes, seconds.` I also have a variable (of `VARCHAR2` type), that has information of only `day, month, year`. `(l_attr_val = '06/21/2017')`. Now I want to make an equality filter between this variable and values stored in table, based only on date, without time (I get 21st of June 2017 in variable and I want to see all records from 21st of June 2017, no matter the time).

```
SELECT * FROM date_test WHERE date_in_date = TO_DATE('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

It gives me 0 rows because of the times.

CASE 2, separate from CASE 1:
CASE 1: Date is stored in `VARCHAR2` column and it has information about `day, month, year, hour, minutes, seconds.` I also have a variable (of `VARCHAR2` type), that has information of only `day, month, year`. `(l_attr_val = '06/21/2017')`. Now I want to make an equality filter between this variable and values stored in table, based only on date, without time (I get 21st of June 2017 in variable and I want to see all records from 21st of June 2017, no matter the time).

```
SELECT * FROM date_test WHERE TO_DATE(date_in_varchar, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM' = TO_DATE('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

So, what is the safest way to compare dates in above mentioned cases?

Comment: Why deal with this questions?  Just store dates in the database using `date`.  When you return values, you can use `to_char()` to format it however you like.

Comment: Why do you have to store the date as a string at all? Just store the actual date as the right data type, and let the client format as a string as necessary. And only ever use actual dates to filter, as your PL/SQL block is doing. (If really necessary you could add a virtual column (11g+) which formats the date as a string, or a view on top of the table, but still don't filter against that string value).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately, in project that I am working on some dates are stored in varchar columns and I have to handle it. Yes, it would be much simpler if all dates were stored in DATE columns. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Your sample data has both values set in all rows. Can you actually have rows with only varchar2, or only date (or neither)? What if the date and varchar2 values don't match, or the varchar2 isn't in the format you expect? Seems like an odd data model that is going to continue to cause you problems...

Comment: @AlexPoole - Yes, I have rows with only varchar2 or only date. Values in these two don't necessarily have to match. Also I expect that varchar2 will always have expected format. This simple table was only for example and I'm working on two different comparisons.

Comment: `I think it would work properly for date stored in date (if I am wrong please tell me why)` - your query would work if all the dates in the date_in_date column are set to midnight; if you can have actual times in there, you'd need to check a range, e.g. `date_in_date >= TO_DATE(l_attr_val, 'MM/DD/YYYY') and date_in_date < TO_DATE(l_attr_val, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + 1`

Comment: If the date and varchar don't match which will you use? I think you need to edit your question to explain what you are really doing and what rules you need to enforce more clearly.

Comment: @AlexPoole I edited my post. Is it more clear now, what I'm asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Case 1: Properly stored dates (date type)***

You could convert your `date_in_date` column to drop time part but this would not take advantage of non-functional index on this colum so I would advise not to go that way. Instead, if `06/22/2017` is your `VARCHAR2` type variable you could also modify it on the fly to have one more value which is incremented by 1 day. This would make use of plain index on `date_in_date` function and the query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM date_test
WHERE date_in_date >= TO_DATE('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND date_in_date < TO_DATE('06/23/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

You could also add +1 after the second part and use the same variable to save you the time for doing math by yourself on a variable.

***Case 2: Dates stored as varchars***

You need to convert your `date_in_varchar` to date without time part (or with it, and then partially apply logic proposed for case 1) and also convert your input variable the same way. If you decide to convert it to date without time part then below query would take advantage of functional index (but not a plain one):

```
SELECT * FROM date_test
WHERE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(date_in_varchar, 0, 12), 'MM/DD/YYYY') = TO_DATE('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Should you decide on converting it to a date with time part query would be similar to case 1, but with proper formating. I would advise you to create a functional index on this conversion to date with trimming the varchar to characters containing only date if your queries are going to be accurate up to one day.

Comment: In the first query the first condition needs to be `>=` or it'll miss any value that are at exactly midnight. In your second query you would get ORA-01830 with the sample data, so you really need to give the whole format, and then either truncate it back to midnight or use the same range logic.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for your input. I'm far from knowing Oracle well. :-) I've updated my answer with a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

If there are indexes on these columns I would use:

Case 1:

```
select * from date_test 
  where date_in_date >= to_date('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')  
    and date_in_date <  to_date('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + 1;
```

Case 2:

```
 select * from date_test where date_in_varchar like '06/22/2017%'
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I used below approach:

**Case 1: Properly stored dates (date type)**

```
SELECT * FROM date_test 
WHERE TRUNC(date_in_date)= to_date('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'nls_date_language = ENGLISH');
```

**Case 2: Dates stored as varchars**

```
SELECT * FROM date_test
WHERE TRUNC(TO_DATE(date_in_varchar, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) = to_date('06/22/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'nls_date_language = ENGLISH');
```